# f.lux overrides media player classic settings

Tags: brightness, f.lux

I've bin using f.lux for a while and its a great app.

As for me, the only (tiny) drawback that makes f.lux almost perfect but not completely perfect - is some issue that I'm having with video players.

Since I've installed f.lux I can't make any changes in video player settings.
Eg - brightness of video player window does not change a bit even if I put "brightness slider" ( in video player settings)  to extreme values.

It's like f.lux overrides or prohibits all the other apps from making changes **even when f.lux is paused or disabled**.

Is there any way to workaround that little problem in this , otherwise  great app ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've got it.
Somehow f.lux disabled all media player applications to make any changes.

**Solution ( win 7):**

right click on desktop / graphic properties / advanced mode / media

In Standard Color Correction tab,  select "APPLICATION SETTINGS" in drop down menu instead of "Driver settings". Click OK and you're done